# How does the compiler handle subtraction of unsigned integers?

Tags: c

I am unable to understand a simple arithmetic operation between two unsigned integers; why is the result "`802`"? 
Assuming integer number size is `32`-bits guaranteed by compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    uint32_t Temp1;
    Temp1 = (uint32_t)801 - (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF; // Two Unsigned Integers

    uint32_t Temp2;
    Temp2 = 801 - 0xFFFFFFFF;// Two Signed Integers and result assigned to unsigned


    unsigned int Temp3;
    Temp3 = (unsigned int)((unsigned int)801 - (unsigned int)0xFFFFFFFF); // Two Unsigned Integers

    int32_t Temp4;
    Temp4 = 801 - 0xFFFFFFFF;// Two Signed Integers

    printf("Temp1: %d %u\n",Temp1,Temp1 );
    printf("Temp2: %d %u\n",Temp2,Temp2 );
    printf("Temp3: %d %u\n",Temp3,Temp3 );
    printf("Temp4: %d %u\n",Temp4,Temp4 );  
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Temp1: 802 802
Temp2: 802 802
Temp3: 802 802
Temp4: 802 802
```

How compiler will deal with it if I put the expression in an `if` condition? Will it cast the expression `((uint32_t)OPERAND_1 - (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF)` to signed integer or unsigned integer, and then evaluate?

```
if(((uint32_t)801 - (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF) > (uint16_t)1500)
{
    printf("Hello All\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Hello None\n");
}
```

Comment: `- 0xFFFFFFFF` => `+ 1` when ints are 32 bit.

Comment: It would help if you told us what you expected to get in each case.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre need some clarification example if you don't mind. Thank you

Comment: @zwol I need to now how compiler decides to store 802 in variables

Comment: Looks like you're underflowing.

Comment: I'm not sure I can create an answer which isn't ``implementation defined. Let's say that subbing `0xFFFFFFFF` is like adding `1` when integer is on 32 bits. `0xFFFFFFFF` is `-1`

Comment: @HassaanShah I don't know how to explain that to you unless first you tell us what you thought would happen instead.

Comment: Your question is poorly formed because the literals 801 and 0xFFFFFFFF are both _signed_.  It is a legitimate question, but the code you are using as an example is not semantically when you think it means.  `uint32_t Temp2 = 801u - 0xFFFFFFFFu;` would better illustrate your question because then it is actually unsigned arithmetic.  It will nonetheless produce the same result, at the machine level there is no real distinction between signed and unsigned, it is just a matter of interpretation of the place-value of the  MSB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hexadecimal constant `0xFFFFFFFF`, assuming an `int` is 32-bit, has type `unsigned int`.  As a result, when used in an expression with `801`, which has type `int`, the latter is converted to type `unsigned int` as a result of the **usual arithmetic conversions**.

At no point in the above examples is arithmetic being done on signed types, so there is no implementation defined behavior regarding signed wraparound or the representation of negative numbers.

Section 6.3.1.8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says the following regarding conversion of integer types:

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser 
>   integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
>   with greater rank.
>
> **Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has 
>   rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other 
>   operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>   type.**
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the  operand  with  unsigned  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise,   both   operands   are   converted   to   the   unsigned
>   integer   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>   integer type

The third paragraph is the one that takes effect in this case, since `int` and `unsigned int` are of the same rank.  This means that all arithmetic above is done on `unsigned int` types.

Operations on this type happen modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, which effectively means that the values wrap around.  Subtracting `0xFFFFFFFF` from `801` wraps around to result in 802, which is what gets printed in all cases.

To elaborate on the wraparound behavior, let's take as an example an unsigned 3-bit integer type which can have values 0 thru 7.  Suppose we were to calculate 3 - 7 with this type.  This is analogous to the subtraction you're doing since the value being subtracted is the maximum value the datatype can hold.

Now we subtract:

- 3 - 1 = 2
- 3 - 2 = 1
- 3 - 3 = 0
- 3 - 4 = 7
- 3 - 5 = 6
- 3 - 6 = 5
- 3 - 7 = 4

Note how the value wraps around once the second operand is larger than the first, and that effective result is the same as adding 1.  This is the same as in your examples.

Comment: provided that `int` is 32 bit, which isn't guaranteed in all compilers.

Comment: @dbush Ignoring temp2 and temp4 case why Temp1 and Temp3 are showing 802..I am getting a little bit understanding a more brief description will help a lot. Thank you

Comment: @HassaanShah See my updated example.  That should illustrate what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

In C, the unsigned arithmetic is done at modulo 2^n, where n are the number of bits of the unsigned integer.

Comment: Yes. `801 + 0xFFFFFFF` = `0x00000321 + 0xFFFFFFF` = `0x100000320`, but that won't fit in 32 bits so the high bits get discarded leaving you with `0x00000320` (802).

Comment: @Brendan: hmm. I think you did two typos: `+` instead of `-`. (but result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, computers use what's called 2's complement to represent signed integers. `0xFFFFFFFF` is `-1` for 4 bytes int. 
 [Two's complement - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    uint32_t Temp1;
    Temp1 = (uint32_t)801 - (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF; // Two Unsigned Integers

    uint32_t Temp2;
    Temp2 = 801 - 0xFFFFFFFF; // Two Signed Integers and result assigned to unsigned

    unsigned int Temp3;
    Temp3 = (unsigned int)((unsigned int)801 - (unsigned int)0xFFFFFFFF); // Two Unsigned Integers

    int32_t Temp4;
    Temp4 = 801 - 0xFFFFFFFF; // Two Signed Integers


    printf("Temp1: %d %X %u %d\n",Temp1,Temp1, Temp1, 0xFFFFFFFF );
    printf("Temp2: %d %X %u %X\n",Temp2,Temp2, Temp2, 0xFFFFFFFF );
    printf("Temp3: %d %X %u %u\n",Temp3,Temp3, Temp3, 0xFFFFFFFF );
    printf("Temp4: %d %X %u %x\n",Temp4,Temp4, Temp4, 0xFFFFFFFF );
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Temp1: 802 322 802 -1                                                                                                                          
Temp2: 802 322 802 FFFFFFFF                                                                                                                    
Temp3: 802 322 802 4294967295                                                                                                                  
Temp4: 802 322 802 ffffffff
```

Comment: But I am using uint32_t which is actually unsigned int of 32-bits

Comment: And such behaviour is expected on all C codes. 2 complements it is not required by C (1 complement is also permitted, or just a trap in case of under/overflow but just for signed integers)

Comment: @HassaanShah : but you are not using unsigned arithmetic: In the expression    `Temp2 = 801 - 0xFFFFFFFF` both operands are _signed_ - the only _unsigned_ value is `Temp2 `.  There is an implicit cast to _unsigned_ in the _assignment_(=), so there is no surprise `801 - -1` is `801 +1`.  That said you'd get the same result from ``Temp2 = 801u - 0xFFFFFFFFu` for reasons explained elsewhere.

Comment: @Clifford This *is* using unsigned arithmetic.  According to 6.4.4.1 of the standard, a hex constant with no suffix will try to fit in an `int`, then `unsigned int`.  Assuming a 32-bit `int`, `0xFFFFFFFF` is out of range for `int` but not `unsigned int` so its type is `unsigned int`.  Subsequently, `801` is converted to `unsigned int` via the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: Two's complement has nothing to do with unsigned integers, which are treated as `mod 2^32`, and not as signed things.

Answer (score 0):

In clock arithmetic, if you add to a set of numbers the modulus minus one, the net effect is the same as adding 1.  On the other side, substracting modulo minus 1 to a number has de effect of adding one.  If you subtract 11h to 06h you get 07h in the clock.  In this case you are substracting `2^32 - 1` to `801`, and that should be a negative number.  To conserve unsignedness, you have to add `2^32` to the result, to get the number fitting in the `0..2^32-1` range, so that is `801 - (2^32 - 1) + 2^32 = 801 - 2^32 + 2^32 -(-1) = 802`.